# Turning one edge into multiple to round out a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, edges

I'm trying to understand how this person took one sharp edge and turned it into a soft curve.
They started from this:
[image: Text]
and with pulling the mouse, they went to this:
[image: Text]
There's no screencast keys and I can't figure out how to word it correctly in google to get the answer I'm looking for.
Is this even possible?
Or did he just have all 7 edges in the same place, then scaled them together for an even curve?

The video does not show anything beyond these two screenshots, but you can find where I got them from here: https://youtu.be/VdhRsAUANyI?t=187

Comment: Ctrl+E > Bevel Edges or just Ctrl+B then drag and use wheel to increase segments

Comment: Thank you so much @calambre !!